# Как передать матрицу строк через сокеты в среде C++ Builder?

Tags: c++builder, tcp-ip, сокет, клиент-сервер

Есть матрица строк, которую необходимо передать через сокеты.

Наивная реализация.

Для клиента

```
for (int i = 0; i < rc; i++)
for (int j = 0; j < cc; j++)
{
 AnsiString data = Socket->ReceiveText();
 StringGrid1->Cells[j][i] = data;
}
```

Для cервера:

```
for (int i = 0; i < RowCount; i++)
for (int j = 0; j < ColCount; j++)
 Socket->SendText(asdatabase[i][j]);
```

Вызвала блокировку клиента.

Как можно послать всю матрицу целиком или частично на клиент без его блокировки?

Comment: ReceiveText не знает, сколько именно нужно читать. Поэтому, он читает сколько, сколько есть. С другой стороны, если Вы послали 10 строк с помощью SendText, это абсолютно не значит, что с другой стороны придет ReceiveText отработает 10 раз. Может 1 раз, может 2. А может и 30. 
Поэтому: сервер должен вставлять разделители. А клиент должен уметь корректно вычитывать и разделять по разделителям.

Comment: Я пытался послать всю матрицу целиком через SendBuf, но приходит не она. Точнее приходит матрица того же размера с пустыми ячейками.

Comment: А как Вы это делаете?

Comment: Более подробно напишу.
На сервере:

    Socket->SendBuf(&RowCount,sizeof(int));
    Socket->SendBuf(&N,sizeof(int));
    Socket->SendBuf(asdatabase,sizeof(AnsiString)*RowCount*N);

На клиенте:

    Socket->ReceiveBuf(&rc,sizeof(int));
    Socket->ReceiveBuf(&cc,sizeof(int));
    AnsiString data[30][30];
    Socket->ReceiveBuf(data,sizeof(AnsiString)*900); //максимальное выделение

Я понимаю, что вряд ли это правильно, но у каждой ячейки своя длина...

Первые две строки работают на ура в обоих приложениях

Comment: А Вы так распечатайте `sizeof(AnsiString)` - это скорее всего будет 4. То есть, Вы передаете не строку, а адрес строки в памяти. С вероятностью 146% на клиенте по этим адресам будет мусор. 

Подумайте, какие данные там хранятся. Строки? числа? Возможно, самый простой способ, сложить все это в TStringList (построчно). А потом, воспользовавшись его методом text, передать строкой (и перед этим передайте размер строки!). На другом конце прочитайте размер, потом вычитайте строку и в TStringList поместите. Разложить в грид не так сложно.

Comment: Строки там хранятся. Я попытался ещё посчитать общее количество символов, чтобы чётко сказать, сколько байт передать, но безрезультатно.

Comment: Переделайте ваш комментарий в ответ. Эта идея мне помогла, хоть я и реализовал её в несколько другом виде. В любом случае данные необходимо сериализовать, прежде чем передавать.

Answer (score 1):

Сервер:

```
ServerSocket1->Socket->SendBuf(&svArray,sizeof(svArray));
```

svArray - имя массива на сервере.

Клиент:
В событии OnRead.

```
Socket->RecieveBuf(&clArray,Socket->RecieveLength());
```

clArray - имя массива на клиенте, такой же размерности как и на сервере.

Comment: В Вашем коде есть две грубые ошибки. Найдете сами?

Comment: Ну видимо нет. Не подскажешь?

Comment: в каждой строке по одной ошибке. 

1) `sizeof(svArray)` - это будет работать, только если массив статический. Если там динамический массив или вектор, то ничего работать не будет. А тип переменной `svArray` не указали.

2) `sizeof(Socket->RecieveLength())` - размер чего?

Comment: 1) В данном вопросе вроде как про динамику ничего не спрашивалось. Зачем указывать тип если это обобщенный пример?
2) Размер передаваемого сервером буфера.

Comment: 1) как раз для обобщенного примера нужно писать `len(array) * sizeof(тип-элемента)` len - нужно заменить на правильную в контексте функцию.

2) если бы написали просто `Socket->RecieveLength()`, без sizeof, тогда это ещё нормально. Хотя и печально. Это tcp, здесь нет никакой гарантии, что в буфере придут все передаваемые данные одним пакетом. Поэтому обычно вначале передают размер, а потом по этому размеру и вычитывают.

Comment: 1) Учту.
2) Я и не заметил что там sizeof, мой косяк.